# Linq2Rest doesn't work on nested properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an API that returns c# objects serialized as JSON.

I need to implement some sort of OData format parsing on my API URLs.
That for example, originally look like this: 
[http://api.loc/userprofiles/all/?$orderby=ProfileProperties.Email](http://api.loc/userprofiles/all/?%24orderby=SeoProperties.TitleOverride)

I was looking for some more or less straightforward library that would allow me to parse the Filter / OrderBy (OData) query string and apply a Filter on my data source. I found **[Linq2Rest](http://linq2rest.codeplex.com/)** with it's pretty simple format where I can use it like:

```
var filtered = allItems.Filter(Request.Params).OfType<Content.UserProfile>();
```

Problem is that my Content.UserProfile has a nested property .ProfileProperties, which contains the properties that I'm interested in

So, for example:

```
var user = new Content.UserProfile();
user.ProfileProperties.Email = "my@mail.com";
user.ProfileProperties.FirstName = "Fukoka";
```

.. etc

Unfortunately Linq2Rest can't parse my query and fails with a message 
**"ProfileProperties.Email is not recognized as a valid property"** ..

How can I then perform this Filter on items with nested properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the query URL a generated one, or did you write it yourself? I would have expected it to be:

```
http://api.loc/userprofiles/all/?$orderby=ProfileProperties/Email
```

Normally with OData nested properties use a slash ( / ) as separator.

Otherwise, you should include some information about how the query URL is generated.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be working now. Phew :) Yes the initial URL was written by me (I was testing the new thing..).. Now as this step seems to be solved, my next question would be - how should I generate those URL's on the client ? Could you please direct me on this ? :)

Comment: Linq2Rest has a client side part as well. Have a look at this tutorial: http://reimers.dk/tutorials/using-linq2rest-as-a-client

Comment: Thank you! I found this page, but I was struggling to find implementation for IRestClient; What if I don't need any client and de-serializing. I only need Linq2Rest to create that proper query string (in URL) from Linq expression (applied even on that 'dummy' property - Provider.Query)

Comment: The Linq2Rest library has an undocumented class, ODataExpressionConverter - https://bitbucket.org/jjrdk/linq2rest/src/b98c5646263701cc1d96847622a6577ce4c8fa4f/Linq2Rest/Provider/ODataExpressionConverter.cs?at=default. Create an instance of this and use the Convert method to convert an expression to an OData filter.

Comment: You Rock! Thanks so much, your library has everything I need for the perfect API :) and a special thank you for being so responsive!

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
[OData Client Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668772%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  provided by Microsoft.

Is there any specific reason you are not using it ?

Example taken from [Query Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673933%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

// Define a query for orders with a Freight value greater than 30 
// and that is ordered by the ship date, descending.

```
  DataServiceQuery<Order> selectedOrders = context.Orders
    .AddQueryOption("$filter", "Freight gt 30")
    .AddQueryOption("$orderby", "OrderID desc");
```